# Pass data in navigator.pushNamed

Tags: flutter, routes, navigation

I want to pass data from list_screen to tenancyDetailsScreen, but I stuck at the routes page.

**list_screen.dart**

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, AppRoute.tenancyDetailsScreen,arguments:tenancy[index]);
```

**app_route.dart**

```
class AppRoute {
  static const tenancyDetailsScreen = '/tenancyDetailsScreen';

  static final _tenancyDetailsScreenRoute = Routes(tenancyDetailsScreen,TenancyDetailsScreen());

  static Route? onGenerateRoutes(RouteSettings settings) {
          
    if(settings.name == tenancyDetailsScreen){
      final args = settings.arguments as Tenancy;  // how to pass this args to DetailsScreen? 
      return _tenancyDetailsScreenRoute.materialRoute;
    }
      ....
  }
}
```

**routes.dart**

```
class Routes extends Equatable {
  final String route;
  final Widget page;

  const Routes(this.route, this.page);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [
        route,
      ];

  get materialRoute => MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_) => SafeArea(child: page),
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass an arguments, you can't use custom `Routes`.

```
static Route? onGenerateRoutes(RouteSettings settings) {
          
    if(settings.name == tenancyDetailsScreen){
      final args = settings.arguments as Tenancy;  // how to pass this args to DetailsScreen? 
      return MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_) => SafeArea(child: TenancyDetailsScreen(tenancy: args)),
      );
    }
      ....
  }
```